# JLabel, setText using an interface does not work

Tags: java, swing, interface, jlabel, settext

I am working on a little project and want to display the Name of the opened File.
The problem is, the JLabel who should display the File Name is not repainting, I had read that it should be repainted by itself..

here is my code for the FileChooser and to get the File Name ( I know that i get the path of the file, I will format it later..

```
     /**
     * Opens a window where the user can select a file.
     *
     * @return Scanner in
     */
    public Scanner openFile() {
        JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
        Scanner in = null;
        if (chooser.showOpenDialog(null) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
            File selectedInFile = chooser.getSelectedFile();
            try {
                absolutePathOfFile = selectedInFile.getAbsolutePath();
                FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(selectedInFile.getAbsolutePath());
                in = new Scanner(fileReader);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
                // File not found
                System.out.println("File not found!!");
            }
        }
        return in;
    }

    public List getList() {
        return listOfEveryVariable;
    }

    @Override
    public String getFileName() {
        return absolutePathOfFile;
    }
```

And here is the code for my Label

```
public Component createInfoPanel() {
    infoPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
    infoPanel.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);

    fileInfoPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1,2));
    fileInfoPanel.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
    infoPanel.add(fileInfoPanel, BorderLayout.WEST);

    JLabel fileInfo_1 = new JLabel();
    fileInfo_1.setText("File: ");
    fileInfoPanel.add(fileInfo_1);

    JLabel fileInfo_2 = new JLabel();
    FileName fn = new Datahandler();
    fileInfo_2.setText(fn.getFileName());
    fileInfoPanel.add(fileInfo_2);

    return infoPanel;
}
```

The GuiInfoPanel is created and added in and to an Frame..

If I set a name to the getFileName() class and let it return it works and the name is displayed.

Greetings

---

The createInfoPanel is called here:

```
public class GuiFrame extends JFrame {

    private static final int FRAME_WIDTH = 800;
    private static final int FRAME_HIGHT = 600;

    /**
     * The variables for the panels
     */
    private JPanel  mainPanel, menuPanel, plotPanel, scatterplotPanel,
                    histogramPanel, histogram1, histogram2;

    public GuiFrame() {
    setSize(FRAME_WIDTH, FRAME_HIGHT);
    /**
     * Create Objects
     */
    GuiMenuBar mb = new GuiMenuBar();
    GuiInfoPanel ip = new GuiInfoPanel();
    GuiOptionPanel op = new GuiOptionPanel();
    JComponent sp = new Scatterplot();
    /**
     * Create Panels
     */
    createMainPanel();
    mb.createMenuBar();
    ip.createInfoPanel();
    op.createOptionPanel();

    /**
     * Add Panels
     */
    this.add(mainPanel);
    this.setJMenuBar(mb);
    this.add(ip.infoPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    menuPanel.add(op.optionPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    scatterplotPanel.add(sp, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }




    private Component createMainPanel(){
        mainPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());

        menuPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        mainPanel.add(menuPanel, BorderLayout.WEST);

        plotPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(2,1));   
        plotPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black));
        mainPanel.add(plotPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        scatterplotPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        scatterplotPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black));
        plotPanel.add(scatterplotPanel);

        histogramPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1,2));
        plotPanel.add(histogramPanel);

        histogram1 = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        histogram1.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black));
        histogramPanel.add(histogram1);

        histogram2 = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        histogram2.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black));
        histogramPanel.add(histogram2);

        return mainPanel;    
    }
}
```

I think that the panel being called only once is be the problem.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example) or [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example).

Comment: is `Datahandler fn` is same object by which you open a file? In which order they act? first you open a file then create a `GuiInfoPanel`, or you create `fn`, then open a file in it?

Comment: Ich firs create the Label, when the Program is running the Label should be empty. I oben a file while using an open button. Later I would like to open an other file and the name of the File should be changes. The object fn is created at the beginning when no file is opened.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the problem is that createInfoPanel() is only ever called once, at the point where you create the screen. At this point, setText() is doing what you'd expect it to, but the user hasn't chosen a file yet. I am basing this on the fact that if createInfoPanel() were called multiple times, you would end up adding more labels to the screen than desired.

When you select a file from your file chooser, createInfoPanel() doesn't magically get called again and so the text never gets updated on the JLabel. It would be useful to see the code that calls createInfoPanel() and the code that calls openFile() to verify this is the case.

Regarding your second question - you can't reference the JLabel outside of where it is declared. As you are declaring the JLabel within createInfoPanel() it is a local variable to this method only. If you want it to be accessed by other methods you need to make it a class variable, similar to the "absolutePathOfFile" variable. So you might do something like:

```
public class GuiInfoPanel {

    private final JPanel infoPanel;
    private final JLabel fileInfo = new JLabel();

    public Component createInfoPanel() {
        infoPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        infoPanel.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);

        fileInfo.setText("File: ");
        infoPanel.add(fileInfo, BorderLayout.WEST); 

        return infoPanel;
    }

    /**
     * Call this whenever the user picks a new file
     */
    public void setFileInfoText(String filePath){
        fileInfo.setText("File: " + filePath);
    }
}
```

EDIT: Your latest code confirms my suspicions - createInfoPanel() is only called by the constructor, so will only be called once. Try something like my code snippet above to get the behaviour you're after. And a side-note: You should edit your original post to include more information rather than posting updates as 'answers'!

EDIT 2: See below for a self-contained 'toy' example that should help you to get the behaviour you're after.

```
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.File;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

public class FileSelectionDemo extends JFrame
                               implements ActionListener
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        FileSelectionDemo demoScreen = new FileSelectionDemo();
        demoScreen.setSize(300, 300);
        demoScreen.setVisible(true);
    }

    public FileSelectionDemo() 
    {
        getContentPane().setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER, 5, 5));
        getContentPane().add(btnSelectFile);
        getContentPane().add(lblFilePath);

        btnSelectFile.addActionListener(this);
    }

    private final JLabel lblFilePath = new JLabel("");
    private final JButton btnSelectFile = new JButton("Choose File");

    public void selectFile() 
    {
        JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
        if (chooser.showOpenDialog(null) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) 
        {
            File selectedInFile = chooser.getSelectedFile();
            String absolutePathOfFile = selectedInFile.getAbsolutePath();
            lblFilePath.setText(absolutePathOfFile);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0)
    {
        Object source = arg0.getSource();
        if (source == btnSelectFile)
        {
            selectFile();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thx man, I tryed that but it doesn´t work :/ I can print the filePhat when calling setFileInfoText but the label don´t get updated. Sorry for using the wrong button, I will do it better next time ;)

Comment: I've edited my answer to include a short, self-contained example of setText() working. Using this, you should be able to spot the problem in your own code. Notice how setText() is explicitly being called every time a file is selected - you need to replicate this behaviour in your code.